# MLE of Negative Binomial Distribution

Tags: probability, maxima-minima, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation

I want to find an estimator of the probability of success of an independently repeated Bernoulli experiment. Given that we have exactly $k$ failures before the $r$-th success.

The probability for $k$ failures before the $r$-th success is given by the *negative binomial distribution*:

$$P_p[\{k\}] = {k + r - 1 \choose k}(1-p)^kp^r$$

This yields the $\log$-Likelihood function for the observed number of failures $k$:

$$l_k(p) = \log({k + r - 1 \choose k}) + k\log(1-p) + r\log(p)$$

With derivative

$$l_k'(p) = \frac{r}{p} - \frac{k}{1-p}$$

The derivative is zero at $\hat p = \frac{r}{r+k}$. To show that $\hat p$ is really a MLE for $p$ we need to show that it is a maximum of $l_k$. But evaluating the second derivative at this point is pretty messy. Is there an easier way to show that this is in fact an MLE for $p$?

Comment: When you evaluate the MLE a product sign or sigma sign is involved. Or do you just looking for the maximum of the negative binominal distribution?

Comment: @callculus Why is there a product or sum involved?

Comment: user7802048 any further questions?

Answer (score 1):

In general the method of MLE is to maximize $L(\theta;x_i)=\prod_{i=1}^n(\theta,x_i)$. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2793538/144421) for instance. In case of the negative binomial distribution we have

$$L(p;x_i) = \prod_{i=1}^{n}{x_i + r - 1 \choose k}p^{r}(1-p)^{x_i}\\$$

$$
\ell(p;x_i) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left[\log{x_i + r - 1 \choose k}+r\log(p)+x_i\log(1-p)\right]$$
$$\frac{d\ell(p;x_i)}{dp} = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left[\dfrac{r}{p}-\frac{x_i}{1-p}\right]=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \dfrac{r}{p}-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{x_i}{1-p}$$

Set it to zero and add $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{x_i}{1-p}$ on both sides.

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \dfrac{r}{p}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{x_i}{1-p}$$

$$\frac{nr}{p}=\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^nx_i}{1-p}\Rightarrow \hat p=\frac{\frac{1}{\sum x_i}}{\frac{1}{n r}+\frac{1}{\sum x_i}}\Rightarrow \hat p=\frac{r}{\overline x+r}$$

Now we have to check if the mle is a maximum. For this purpose we calculate the second derivative of $\ell(p;x_i)$.

$$\frac{d^2\ell(p;x_i)}{dp^2}=\underbrace{-\frac{rn}{p^2}}_{<0}\underbrace{-\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i}{(1-p)^2}}_{<0}<0\Rightarrow \hat p\textrm{ is a maximum}$$

Comment: Why do you need the product? I'm not required to looking at a joint distribution of multiple negative binomial distributions?

Comment: You have a sample of n values ($x_i$). Based on this (fix) values you estimate the parameter. For this propose we maximize the product of $f(x_i,\theta)\cdot \ldots \cdot f(x_n, \theta)$

Comment: And isn't the second derivative of $\mathcal{l}$ equal to $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i}{(1-p)^2} - \frac{rn}{p^2}$ (notice the positive sign)?

Comment: But in my question I stated, that I just have one sample..

Comment: If the sample size is 1 then  $n=1$. Have you read the link?

Comment: Yes, I've read the link and I understand using the joint density, if we have multiple samples, but I don't see the point of introducing the general case of $n$ samples, when only one sample is of significance.

Comment: This are not multiple samples. You have **one sample** with a sample size of $n$!!! It has nothing to do with joint densities.

Comment: But the product you use is the joint density of $n$ independent negative binomial distributions isn't it? I think we talk past each other at this point. But can you explain, the second derivative a little bit further? I'm confused about the negative sign in front of the second fraction.

Comment: By the way the derivative of $-\frac1{1-p}=-(1-p)^{-1}$ is $(-1)\cdot -(1-p)^{-2}\cdot (-1)=-\frac{1}{(1-p)^2}$. You have to regard the chain rule. The derivative of $(1-p)$ is $-1$

Comment: Again. MLE has nothing to do with a joint density. Maybe you trust wiki a little more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation). Here they talk about "observed data". The sample could be $3,5,3,2$ if $n=4$ There is no randomness involved.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96655/discussion-between-user7802048-and-callculus).

Comment: @callculus42 How can we show the MLE is biased here?